# Slack: How can I remove a message's action buttons without Slack appending "edited"

Tags: slack, slack-api, botkit

I have a Slackbot message that has action buttons ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wb9t.png)). When a user click's a button, we perform a bit of work on our server and then use [chat.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update) to remove the action buttons and update the message's footer:

```
removeButtons(reply, convo, footer) {

  const data = reply.original_message;
  delete data.attachments[0].actions;
  data.channel = reply.channel;
  if (footer) {
    data.attachments[0].footer = footer;
  }
  this.bot.api.chat.update(data, (res) => {

  });
}
```

Everything is working great but Slack appends an "(Edited)" to the message. I see a lot of other apps doing the same, but they seem to avoid the "(Edited)" text? What are they doing differently?

I've tried setting `as_user` and `replace_original` in the `chat.update` call but haven't had any luck.

[Slack Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wb9t.png)

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to "update" a message as result of an interaction.

1. Use the API method [chat.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update) (as you described)
2. [Respond directly](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages#responding) to the slack request with a new message

With 2) the original message will be replaced by default and there will be no "edited" note.